# Shape change error in ctc_batch_cost function with TensorFlow 2.7.0

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, ctc

I have some code that generates a `CTC` layer which no longer works in TensorFlow `2.7.0` but works in `2.6.1`. The code in question which is causing the problem is:

```py
class CTCLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.loss_fn = keras.backend.ctc_batch_cost

    def call(self, labels, label_length, predictions): #input_length, 
        batch_len = tf.cast(tf.shape(labels)[0], dtype="int64")
        input_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(predictions)[1], dtype="int64")
        label_length = tf.cast(label_length, dtype="int64")#tf.cast(tf.shape(labels)[1], dtype="int64")

        input_length = input_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")
        label_length = label_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")
        
        loss = self.loss_fn(y_true=labels, y_pred=predictions, input_length=input_length, label_length=label_length)#, logits_time_major=False)
        self.add_loss(loss)

        return predictions
```

and crashes when calling the `ctc_batch_cost` function during model building with the following error:

`ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "CTC_LOSS" (type CTCLayer).`

Traceback:

```
    File "<ipython-input-10-0b2cf7d5ab7d>", line 16, in call  *
        loss = self.loss_fn(y_true=labels, y_pred=predictions, input_length=input_length, label_length=label_length)#, logits_time_major=False)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 6388, in ctc_batch_cost
        ctc_label_dense_to_sparse(y_true, label_length), tf.int32)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 6340, in ctc_label_dense_to_sparse
        range_less_than, label_lengths, initializer=init, parallel_iterations=1)

    ValueError: Input tensor `CTC_LOSS/Cast_5:0` enters the loop with shape (1, 1), but has shape (1, None) after one iteration. To allow the shape to vary across iterations, use the `shape_invariants` argument of tf.while_loop to specify a less-specific shape.


Call arguments received:
  • labels=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1), dtype=int32)
  • label_length=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1), dtype=int32)
  • predictions=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 509, 30), dtype=float32)
```

I suspect the problem is easy to fix and has something to do with the fact that TensorFlow no longer performs upranking as described in the `2.7.0` release notes:

> The methods Model.fit(), Model.predict(), and Model.evaluate() will no longer uprank input data of shape (batch_size,) to become (batch_size, 1). This enables Model subclasses to process scalar data in their train_step()/test_step()/predict_step() methods.
> Note that this change may break certain subclassed models. You can revert back to the previous behavior by adding upranking yourself in the train_step()/test_step()/predict_step() methods, e.g. if x.shape.rank == 1: x = tf.expand_dims(x, axis=-1). Functional models as well as Sequential models built with an explicit input shape are not affected.

Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same issue. Please post if you find a solution.

Comment: Because the `ctc_batch_cost` API is no longer available to use after `TF 2.3`. This API was last available only in `TF 2.3`. You can check the same in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.3/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/ctc_batch_cost)  for `TF 2.3` which is not available in `TF 2.4` and in after TensorFlow versions (find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.4/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend)). Please re-verify if it was supported in `TF 2.6`.